# Azure Function App access to its own storage account with Shared Key Authentication disabled

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-storage-account

In my organization I have a requirement to set **"Allow storage account key access"** on a storage account to **Disabled**, such that Primary and Secondary Access keys cannot be used to connect to the storage account:

[image]

When I create a simple **Consumption** based .NET 3.1 **Function App** in Azure Portal and create a sample Queue Triggered function directly in the Portal, my Function App cannot access anything on its own storage account when I have this "Allow storage account key access" set to Disabled.

I can understand that it cannot access its own binary files which are stored in the storage account's fileshare. I have created a Managed Identity for my Function App and assigned it all these RBAC roles on its own storage account:
[image]

Why can't the Function App not read its own files when I have given all these permissions?
[image]
[image]

My Configuration uses this syntax **AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName**:

[image]

Application Insights is also not available:

[image]

If I set "Allow storage account key access" to **Enabled** then everything works:

[image]

[image]

So how do I go about this simple scenario of having to fulfil the requirement to have "Allow storage account key access" set to **Disabled** and use a .NET **Consumption** based Function App?

**UPDATE:** I've now created a .NET 6 Isolated C# Function and deployed the code to a new FunctionApp with .NET 6 support and used the notation "AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName" in my Configuration and it still doesn't work for me.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE2:** I have managed to get it to work. The trick was to use Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues version 5.x+ as this supports AAD Authentication: [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#storage-extension-5x-and-higher)
You cannot use the Developer Portal under Functions in Function App to test this out. You need to test it out in code.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the Storage Blob Data Contributor role on your Managed Identity at least. How have you setup the connection in the app's settings?

Comment: I have now updated my post and added screenshots where I added Storage Blob Data Owner as well my Configuration. I have just created a Queue Triggered sample Function directly under Function -> Create in the Azure Portal.

Comment: The samples might be depending on shared access key authentication. You might need to modify it to use the managed identity. Especially this part: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial#edit-the-azurewebjobsstorage-configuration

Comment: Maybe you are right that the samples in the Portal are using .Net 3.1 which is not supporting the __accountName syntax. I will try to create a .Net 6 queue triggered function and deploy that one to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

For an Azure Function to read from a Storage Account and its Queue, you need to provide the Storage Queue Data Contributor role on the Storage Account for the Azure Function's Managed Identity.

In order to use Managed Identity and thus AAD Authentication the Azure Function code needs to use version 5.x+ of this package: [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#storage-extension-5x-and-higher)

The .NET 6 Isolated Azure Function that is Queue Triggered looks like this:

```
 public class Function1
 {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue01")] string myQueueItem)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
 }
```

and the local.settings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
     "AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName": "<storage-account-name-here>",
     "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

and when it is Published to an Azure Function App you can just have this configuration: AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName

[image]